# Android rare NPE when accessing fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, listener, activity-lifecycle

I have an activity in Android which contains frame layouts. One of the frame layouts is inflated with a fragment. 
In the `onResume()` of the fragment, a call is made to a listener which is implemented in the Activity.
The listener then calls a method to the fragment. At this point, an NPE occurs on the reference to the fragment.

It happens very rarely, but it has been reproduced at least 2 times. 
I suspect that the problem has to do with the lifecycle of the activity and fragment.
A reference to the fragment is made while the activity is still in the `onCreate()` step of the lifecycle, which may be before the fragment is initialized.

Is my analysis correct? How can I prevent the NPE?

Here is the code (please keep in mind that I have renamed a lot of the code and removed parts that seems irrelevant):

Activity:

```
FoodsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FruitStateFragment.OnAppleSelectedListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private FruitsManager mFruitsManagr;
    private FruitStateFragment mFruitStateFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foods_activity);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mContext == null) {
            mContext = getApplicationContext();
        }
        mFruitsManagr = FruitsManager.get(mContext);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fl_fruits_status) != null) {
            mFruitStateFragment = new FruitStateFragment();
            mFruitStateFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fl_fruits_status, mFruitStateFragment, "FruitStateFragment").commit();
        }

        mFruitsManagr.setApple(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment instanceof FruitStateFragment) {
            FruitStateFragment fruitStateFragment = (FruitStateFragment) fragment;
            fruitStateFragment.setOnAppleSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void onAppleSelected(Integer appleNum) {
        FruitsManager fManager = FruitsManager.get(mContext);
        fManager.setApple(appleNum);
        // NPE on mFruitStateFragment
        mFruitStateFragment.updateBasketUi(fManager.getActiveBasketName());
    }   
}
```

Fragment:

```
FruitStateFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context mContext;

    FruitsManager mFruitsManagr;
    OnAppleSelectedListener mAppleCallback;

    public void setOnAppleSelectedListener(OnAppleSelectedListener callback) {
        this.mAppleCallback = callback;
    }

    public interface OnAppleSelectedListener {
        void onAppleSelected(Integer appleNum);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (mContext == null) {
            mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        }
        mFruitsManagr = FruitsManager.get(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAppleCallback.onAppleSelected(mFruitsManagr.getActiveApple());
    }

    void updateBasketUi(String basketName) {
    }

}
```

Manager:

```
public class FruitsManager {

    private static FruitsManager sMe;
    private Context mContext;

    private static int mActiveApple = 0;
    private static String mActiveBasketName = "";

    private FruitsManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        initInterfaces();
    }

    public int getActiveApple() {
        return mActiveApple;
    }

    public int getActiveBasketName() {
        return mActiveBasketName;
    }

}
```

Log:

```
D FRUITS: 0001 onCreate (FoodsActivity%onCreate:)
D FRUITS: 0002 onCreate (FruitStateFragment%onCreate:)
D FRUITS: 0003 onCreateView (FruitStateFragment%onCreateView:)
D FRUITS: 0004 onActivityCreated (FruitStateFragment%onActivityCreated:)
D FRUITS: 0005 initViews (FruitStateFragment%initViews:)
D FRUITS: 0006 onResume (FruitStateFragment%onResume:)
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.hi/FoodsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.hi.FruitStateFragment.updateBasketUi(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    return;
}
```

Mean that you never set your `mFruitStateFragment` variable when your activity is recreated - you only set it when you first add the fragment. It also means your `mFruitsManagr` and `mContext` is also not set, since it also after that line. If you want those to be available every time your activity is created, you should remove that check and wrap only the things that should only happen once.

That means your activity should instead look like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.foods_activity);

    if (mContext == null) {
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }
    mFruitsManagr = FruitsManager.get(mContext);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mFruitStateFragment = new FruitStateFragment();
        mFruitStateFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fl_fruits_status, mFruitStateFragment, "FruitStateFragment").commit();
        // I assume this shouldn't be set every time the activity
        // is recreated
        mFruitsManagr.setApple(0);
    } else {
        // Get the Fragment that is already created from the FragmentManager
        mFruitStateFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fl_fruits_status);
    }
}
```

Of course, since you're using `onAttachFragment()` you can also get a reference from there as that will be called for every your activity is recreated:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.foods_activity);

    if (mContext == null) {
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }
    mFruitsManagr = FruitsManager.get(mContext);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // We'll store a reference to this in onAttachFragment()
        FruitStateFragment fruitStateFragment = new FruitStateFragment();
        fruitStateFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fl_fruits_status, fruitStateFragment, "FruitStateFragment").commit();
        // I assume this shouldn't be set every time the activity
        // is recreated
        mFruitsManagr.setApple(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment instanceof FruitStateFragment) {
        // This get called every time the activity is created,
        // ensuring that mFruitStateFragment is always set
        mFruitStateFragment = (FruitStateFragment) fragment;
        mFruitStateFragment.setOnSimNumSelectedListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, as well as the suggestion of not calling `.setApple(0)` every time. The code has been changed since I've asked the question, because I realized later that the listener was never necessary. I  implemented your suggestions about `savedIstanceState != null`, and I assume I will not see NPE any more.